# How to impose CSS changes to related sibling element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have multiple parent `div` with pairs of `button` and `div` child elements.

What I want to do is impose changes to the "related" div when a button is clicked. So if Button 2 is clicked, the changes should be imposed on toast 2.
My issue is that no matter the button clicked it's only the first occurrence that is changed.

In my example I set the click to change the `display` value of the relevant element as an example, but in reality any CSS change should be possible.

[Here is a link to a complete and functional codepen as well.](https://codepen.io/PDPal/pen/wvXerme)

```js
function hide() {
  var element = document.querySelector('.toast');
  element.style.display = (element.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position : relative;
  display : inline-block;
  height : 55px;
}

button#button {
  width : 100px;
  height : 35px;
}

.toast {
  display : block;
  position : absolute;
  top : 40px;
  background-color : black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button id="button" onclick="hide()">Button 1</button>
  <div class="toast">A box with text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button id="button" onclick="hide()">Button 2</button>
  <div class="toast">A box with text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button id="button" onclick="hide()">Etc...</button>
  <div class="toast">A box with text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A proper [mre] that reproduces your issue belongs directly into your question; do not just send us to external platforms like codepen to see your code.

Comment: Damn, you're right - added! Apologies!

Comment: your event handler should deal with the target firing the event (`window.event.target`)

Comment: Pass `this` as parameter in the place where you call the function, `onclick="hide(this)"` Then you have access to the specific button element inside your function, and from there you can either go up to the parent using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement, or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest, and then when you have the `. parent` element, you can use `querySelector` or similar DOM methods on that, to find the `.toast` element in there.

Comment: @DiegoD — [`window.event` is deprecated and should be avoided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).

Comment: @Quentin good to know.. it's not the first time I give that suggestion to cut it short... but I wasn't considering the fact you highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't duplicate IDs
- Avoid using `onclick` attributes. They have a number of drawbacks and `addEventListener` makes this easier.
- Pay attention to the event object that is passed to your listener. It will tell you where the click was.
- Navigate up (using `closest`) and down (using `querySelector`) the DOM from that element

```js
function hide(event) {
  // We're using event delegation so if the click isn't from a button we stop immediately
  if (!event.target.matches(".parent button")) {
    return false;
  }
  // Seach from the button up until we find the parent
  const parent = event.target.closest(".parent");
  // Search down from the parent until we find the toast
  const toast = parent.querySelector('.toast');
  toast.style.display = (toast.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}

addEventListener('click', hide);
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55px;
}

.parent button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
}

.toast {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <div class="toast">A box with text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <div class="toast">A box with text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button>Etc...</button>
  <div class="toast">A box with text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, this was it!
But say, if the button(s) contain a nested image, how would I go about modifying the if-statement to register clicks there as well. As it stands it only registers between the image and the edge of the button.

Comment: Use `closest` instead of `matches`.

Comment: I'm learning so much - thank you very much for your time!